# Convert char** to int C++

Tags: c++, char

So I have an array of symbols which has another array of symbols in it (if i'm not wrong). What I need to do is to change third element (`words[2]`). This third element will definitely be a number. I have to increase this number by 15 percent. Therefore, I need to convert `words[2]` to `int`?

Function:

```
void create(char* str) {
    char** words = new char* [strlen(str)];
    int count = 0;
    for (char* part = strtok(str, " "); part != NULL; part = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
        words[count] = _strdup(part);
        count++;
    }

    cout << "\nNew sentence with edited values:" << endl;
    words[2] = words[2] + ((int)words[2] / 100) * 15; //the main problem as I guess
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s ", words[i]);
    }
    cout << endl;
    delete[] words;
}
```

Full code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h> 
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void create(char*);

void main() {
    const int maxLength = 100;
    char* str = new char[maxLength];
    cout << "Enter sentence:\n";
    cin.getline(str, maxLength);
    create(str);
    delete[] str;
}

void create(char* str) {
    char** words = new char* [strlen(str)];
    int count = 0;
    for (char* part = strtok(str, " "); part != NULL; part = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
        words[count] = _strdup(part);
        count++;
    }

    cout << "\nNew sentence with edited values:" << endl;
    words[2] = words[2] + ((int)words[2] / 100) * 15; 
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s ", words[i]);
    }
    cout << endl;
    delete[] words;
}
```

What it needs to look like (3rd element increased by 15 percent):
[image: What it needs to look like]

Cannot do this using `string`. Actually, it is my homework from a university and not using `string` is the condition

Comment: can you share the input and expected output and currently what output you're getting

Comment: Unrelated: You make whatever it is you want done too complicated. Use `std::string`s and `std::vector<std::string>`. There's no need to use `new[]` and `delete[]` for this.

Comment: word[2] is not an integer but characters. (int)word[2] can't be converted to integer by magic. You should use string to integer function like atoi in c or stoi in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert a `char*` to `int` like below. `(int)` casting won't work

```
int a = atoi(words[2]); // make sure words[2] is null terminated
```

Comment: Being a bit pedantic: this code does **not** convert a `char*` to an `int`. It converts the **text** that `words[2]` **points at** to an `int`. Keep the distinction between a pointer and what it points at firmly in your mind; it will save you many headaches. +1.